# SQL help on counts for 2 separate columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I an relatively new to SQL and have an issue with COUNTS for columns.
I have a column for user IDs and a column for sessions IDs in a table.

For example, the columns in the table would look like :

| UserID | SessionID |
| --- | --- |
| 5781647 | hello1 |
| 5781647 | hello2 |
| 5781647 | hello3 |
| 5781647 | hello4 |
| 6847291 | olleh3 |
| 9475728 | test44 |
| 9475728 | nfbfb5 |
| 6748372 | nnnnn4 |

etc....

My end result is to have 2 columns to count the user IDs that have had 1 session in total, that have had 2 sessions in total etc.

Each user ID can have multiple sessions so I want to count how many each of them have had. Using the above example, There is 1 user that has had 4 different sessions, 2 users that have had 1 different session each etc so I would want it to look like this:

| Number of UserIDs | Number of sessions they have had |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

etc ..

I know to obviously `COUNT(userIDs)` but I am struggling with how to code the second column to count the number of distinct sessions for each user while also counting the number of user IDs. I tried

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(USERID),
    COUNT(SESSIONID) 
FROM
    table1
```

etc... but then I obviously have nothing to group by so was unsure what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first count sessions by user and then count users by number of sessions:

```sql
WITH user_sessions AS (
  SELECT 
    userid, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT sessionid) AS sessions
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY userid
)
SELECT
 sessions,
 COUNT(DISTINCT userid) as users
FROM user_sessions 
GROUP BY sessions
ORDER BY sessions ASC
```